# How to change background of barchart?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I have created a BarChart using `jqplot.BarRenderer`. The background of the barchart created is white. I want to change the white background to some other color. I am using [this](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php) sample from jqplot site.

Comment: Based on [this](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html) (outdated, actually) document, you can provide custom color to `options.grid.background = "#666"`; Not sure if it still works. Lack of documentation was surprise for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add option for `$.jqplot` like this.

```
grid: {
    background: '#223344'
}
```

Here is an example. http://jsbin.com/uQupaxi/1/edit?html,output